# Firebase: when onDisconnect event fire?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I`m using Firebase-backend for my android applicaion. I'd like to build a users presence system for my chat. For this purpose I've taken the pattern from Firebase Guide

```
final Firebase myConnectionsRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users/joe/connections");

// stores the timestamp of my last disconnect (the last time I was seen online)
final Firebase lastOnlineRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users/joe/lastOnline");

final Firebase connectedRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/.info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      // add this device to my connections list
      // this value could contain info about the device or a timestamp too
      Firebase con = myConnectionsRef.push();
      con.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);

      // when this device disconnects, remove it
      con.onDisconnect().removeValue();

      // when I disconnect, update the last time I was seen online
      lastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled at .info/connected");
  }
});
```

The trouble is I don't know when **onDisconnect** event would be fired?!

Every time I open the app I write TRUE to the node "**users/joe/connections**" but when I closed app nothing would be happend. 
When I switched WIFI off then the boolean parameter wouldn't be removed as well. 
onDisconnect-event only fired when I forcely stopped my app or reinstalled this app or somewhen else when I couldn`t determine.

So, as I understand right I have to handle manually such events:

1) close my app;

2) switch WiFi off;

3) maybe something else

for creating Presence feature in my app? But then when have **onDisconnect-event** to be fired ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two cases that may happen when the client and server are disconnected:

1. the client explicitly disconnects from the server
2. the client simply disappears

When you kill the app, you are triggering an explicit disconnect. In that case the client will send a signal to the server that it is disconnecting and the server will immediately execute the `onDisconnect` callback.

When you switch off wifi, your app doesn't get a chance to tell the server that it is disconnecting. In that case the `onDisconnect` will fire once the server detects that the client is gone. This may take a few minutes, depending on how the time-outs for sockets are configured. So in that case you just have to be a bit more patient.

It this interval is not granular enough for you, the best you can do is updates a so-called keep-alive value in the database at regular, shorter intervals. That way you can see when the client was most recently active, and act on that if it was too long ago.

Comment: I don't get it. When a user press the BACK button and close all activities, the onDisconnect() doesn't fire. But in this situation, the user should be considering offline, right?

Comment: @iForests I think for `When a user press the BACK button and close all activities` should be handled in _ActivityLifecycleCallbacks_

Comment: @Frank_van_Puffelen how long can it take to its max for the server to detect that the client is gone?
and this is not practical for the server to take minutes because going offline should immediately trigger the related functions in the Firebase Server so that the users understand the status of each other.

Comment: it randomly just doesn't work if the app crashes. I've had values that haven't been changed for days now. Are you sure the server time out works? Do we have to do anything in the project dashboard to configure time-outs?

Comment: No settings are needed, and it's being used in enough projects to be quite certain that it (usually) works. If you have a reproducible case, open a new question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the Firebase support team (also with an MCVE).

Answer (score 0):

When user is exiting the app, you could call `admin.database().goOffline()` to explicitly disconnect from the firebase, which should trigger the `onDisconnect` callback. When user is returning to the app just call `admin.database().goOnline()` to reconnect with firebase.