# Why is Firebase onDisconnect firing every hour?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase app using the javascript web SDK. Our clients are using the custom authentication method. We have implemented a presence system using onDisconnect. We are seeing that onDisconnect fires once every hour, and in most cases the client didn't actually disconnect. This is a problem for us because we are tracking and presenting connect/disconnect events for our clients, and it makes it look like the clients are disconnecting when they aren't.

My guess is that there is some sort of authentication token refresh that is happening every hour, which causes onDisconnect to fire. However, I don't know how to dig in deeper to confirm that or find a different root cause. Can anyone help me figure this out?

It was suggested that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire), but that is about basic onDisconnect operation, and this is about a repeatable observation that onDisconnect fires every hour although the client has not disconnected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: when onDisconnect event fire?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire)

Comment: I don't think so. That question is about the basic behavior of onDisconnect. This question is about my observation that onDisconnect fires every hour for a client that is connected.

Comment: Is it always 1 hour? Fixed for all clients? Whathever their region, country?

Comment: It is always 1 hour, plus or minus a few minutes. We only have clients deployed on the east coast, so I can't answer about region, but the clients are definitely on different networks.

Comment: I should also mention the clients are implemented in Ionic using the Javascript Firebase SDK and are all running on Android.

Comment: If the connection flutters every hour, that is likely related to the access token being refreshed.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. If so, how can I prevent that from happening or ignore it in the server-side code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there any way to prevent the onDisconnect? I'm using this server side and this is causing nasty problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how this `onDisconnect` function is implemented. It would be helpful to explain how you determine the disconnection. Firebase Id tokens expire every hour and need to be refreshed (automatically refreshed after when calling any user method). If you are using real time database, they will try to refresh on expiration. You can add a listener in `onAuthStateChanged` when a token is issued and set a timer to automatically refresh the token (`getToken(true)`) before it expires, ensuring the disconnection does not trigger.

Also, the `onDisconnect` will fail during that disconnection because Firebase consider the token expired.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Firebase Web SDK, you could obtain current token and check its expiration timestamp by calling:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(false); // pass false to retrieve cached token`

You could setup interval to periodically check the token expirationTime and try manually refreshing token just before it expires (for example 60 seconds before it expires) by calling:

`firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true); // pass true to force token refresh`

This should prevent onDisconnect event (`.info/connected` listener) from firing due to token expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `onDisconnect` firing every hour is a bug in the Firebase JS SDK. Normally Firebase Auth will proactively refresh the token before it reaches expiration if consumers such as a database connection exist. If the refresh doesn't happen automatically, the connection gets closed at expiration, and the subsequent reconnect will request a new token, causing it to be refresh then.

I've confirmed that manually starting the proactive refresh logic avoids the hourly disconnect.

I've filed a bug against the SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5498