# Why does Firebase not support onDisconnect when app crashes?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am used that I have a little bug resulting in an app crash. Most likely the bug occurs when querying data from Firebase (yeah yeah, my fault). This is the first function that will be executed when the app launches:

```
let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
            let con = self.gameRef!.childByAutoId()
            self.usersKey = con.key
            let values = ["username": "test", "score": 0, "userID": currentUser!] as [String : Any]
            con.updateChildValues(values)
            con.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
```

Then after this is set, I query for example an array from Firebase but I did set some values wrong what results in an app crash. The onDisconnected function is never executed. I waited for a whole day and my information is still showed in the realtime database. If this code is executed server side, how can it be that the server still thinks I am connected? Closing the app & turning on airplane mode will disconnect me correctly.

Comment: Patience is a virtue here. When the app crashes, the Firebase client doesn't have time to explicitly signal the disconnect. Your `onDisconnect()` handler will still fire, but it takes a few minutes (the time for the socket to time out). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire/30670928#30670928

Comment: How long should I have patience? I already stated in my question that I waited a whole day, trust me it was 24 hours, and it still did NOT disappear.

Comment: As I said in the answer I linked, it may take a few minutes. Longer than that it is more likely that something else went wrong. Also keep in mind that in your example, restarting the app will rewrite the same values.

Comment: Yes, well, I am wondering what else went wrong. Firebase will never see me disconnect when even the app haven't run for over a day... restarting the app actually make another child in my gameRef, I had over 40 childs all with the same UID because Firebase does NOT disconnect me, not in a few minutes, not in a few hours and I think not in a few days. If this function should run on the server it does NOT work when the app crashed. Well, I will let you know whenever it is deleted tomorrow.

Comment: Hmmm.... I think I was able to reproduce the behavior. I'm trying to figure out what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you, I hope you can let me know what was going on :)

Comment: Hmmm... I tried reproducing it in a clean project and now I can't. `let con = self.ref.childByAutoId(); con.setValue("User \(userID) is connected (will be removed onDisconnect)"); con.onDisconnectRemoveValue(); let con2 = self.ref.childByAutoId(); con2.onDisconnectSetValue("User \(userID) disconnected (added onDisconnect)")` (with semicolons to emulate line breaks). When I crash the app (`[][0]`), it removes the first and adds the second instantly.

Comment: I had a function which would retrieve an array from Firebase but with the wrong type, causing a crash. This function would call right after the user connected... I will try to reproduce it in a few hours.

Comment: There is still a problem with this. If the app is left on and the iphone goes to sleep, the server might not set the disconnect value sometimes, and even if i explicitly close the app and switch off the device after that it remains on. It has been almost an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your app isn't shutting down properly. In order for that function to fire it has to be when the app shuts down and cleans up all of its connections. There is no way for it to do this when it crashes because it won't execute any more code than it already did.

You could wrap an exception handler around that part of the code and then execute what you need on that exception.

Comment: There *is* actually a way. But it depends on the server *detecting* the disconnect, which takes some time. See the answer I linked.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks I had no idea that was a thing.

Comment: Since the function relays on the server, the server should check for the connection. When I turn on airplane mode, it handles the disconnect correctly. Not when the app crash.