# How to Use onDisconnect() to Create an Presence System

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make sense out of [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html?m=1) tutorial, but I can't. I am trying to develop a chat app, using Android Studio. In onCreat(), I have this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Online Users").push().setValue(currentUser.getUid());
```

So, immediately after the app gets executed, I will get the UID of the user in Firebase. So far so good. Now, I want the user's UID to be deleted from Firebase immediately after he/she disconnects his/her phone from the internet. Is that possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, and the blog post you link to describes pretty explicitly how to make it work. I recommend following the updated sample in the Firebase documentation, which uses the latest SDKs (the approach is the same though): https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Comment: Weirdly enough, it worked! Thanks for your help. Just one more problem: It takes a very long time, maybe 45 seconds, for firebase to get updated! Is this natural, or there is something I can do about it?

Comment: That depends on whether it was a clean disconnect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire (and probably more from [these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+ondisconnect+slow)).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that I am so lost (I am new to coding)! Correct me if I am wrong, the tutorial I linked to is in javascript. It means I need to deploy them to firebase functions using Node.js, right?

Comment: The link in my first comment is to the Android documentation. Cloud Functions is not involved in any way there. If you're new to this, a presence system is not the easiest to get started with. I'd recommend following the [Firebase codelab for Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) for a more straightforward introduction.