# Firebase Realtime Database - using onDisconnect for Presence

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-presence

I am trying to implement a presence feature in my Firestore app, for orientation I was using the suggested google solution that can be found in the link below (hybrid solution using Firebase Realtime Database and cloud functions):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

I was hoping that the .onDisconnect would fire when I lose internet connection however that only happens after about 60seconds. Is that the normal behaviour of that method or did I do something wrong? I would love if that happened much quicker than that. Any firebase people who can explain what happens under the hood here? Couldn't find anything about triggering conditions for Firebase.Database.onDisconnect. Thank you so much.

Comment: There are two types of disconnects: clean ones (where the app calls the server telling it that it'll close the connection) and dirty ones (where the connection just gets closed). In the latter case it depends on the server to detect that the client is gone. See my longer explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire/30670928#30670928

Comment: Thanks puf, I appreciate your great support here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.  It takes that amount of time to discern if the connection is actually lost, or instead just temporarily blocked for whatever reason.  Basically, 60 seconds is the "timeout" until a read or write on the socket between your client app and the server is expected to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just wondering: do you have any idea on how to achieve a faster performance on that feature? I can't seem to come up with anything..

Comment: The timeout isn't configurable, as far as I know.  You're free to do what you want with the source code, though.  Android, iOS, and web client SDKs are open source.

Comment: I see. However the code that I would want to change would be the server's "understanding" of what a timeout is (e.g. I would like to change that to 10sec). Is that something I can change or isn't that logic running within googles premises? Because what onDisconnect does is essentially just telling the server what I want it to do, should I ever be considered disconnected.

Comment: No, but you can always file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support